# How to start Trade Empires

Tags: trade-empires

I have searched bunch of websites to buy [Trade Empires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trade_Empires) and haven't been able to find it anywhere. I do have old copy on CD but now on Windows 7, it has 2fps, and it is impossible to play. Changing compatibility doesn't work. I googled the problem a bit and I was explained that game just can't recognize my graphic card on Windows 7. Some people suggested to use DOSBox but I don't know how.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Thanks for editing it.  Generally, we're also not going to be able give you a full tutorial on how to use DOSBox.  Is there a specific part about using it that you're not getting?

Comment: If that is the case I will try to set it up again and when I get stuck I'll come back here for guidance :)

Comment: That's perfect.  We're great at specific issues you run into, less so to generic overall tutorials.  So getting stuck and coming to us with that is awesome. :)